# Insert a customer borrowing a particular CD

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

So, I have question on whether the SQL statement for inserting a customer borrowing a particular CD is valid or not.

Here's the form I want the customer to fill out.

```
<form action="proj3.php" method="post">
<h4>Enter regular customer information.</h4>
Customer Name: <input type="text" name="cust_name"><br>
Customer SSN: <input type="text" name="cust_ssn"> (No spaces or special characters)<br>
Customer Telephone number: <input type="text" name="cust_tel"> (No spaces or special characters)   <br>

<h4>Enter existing CD information.</h4>
CD Title: <input type="text" name="cd_title"><br>
CD Year: <input type="text" name="cd_year"><br>

<h4>Enter rent information.</h4>
Start CD Rent Date: <input type="text" name="rent_date"> (Format: YYYY-MM-DD)<br>
Rent Duration (days): <input type="text" name="rent_duration"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here's the E-R diagram I did:

[image]

Now, the backend database stuff I'm definitely very new and a beginner to.

I want to insert a regular customer (non- VIP) that borrows/rents a particular CD. How do I write the SQL statement for that?

Essentially, I'm very confused on what table and attributes should the information go into? I have three tables that relate to this information. CD, rent and customer. What INSERT INTO statement am I writing?

I think it may have something to do with assigning IDs but I'm not sure how to do that yet. If there are any resources or tutorials I should read, please feel free to direct them to me. I'm stuck right now and just want someone to point in toward a certain direction on what steps to take or what to do from here?

EDIT:

Here's my attempt:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO CD ( CD_title, CD_type, CD_year) 
VALUES (‘$_POST[title1]’, ‘$_POST[type1]’, ‘$_POST[year1]’)");
```

But does that take care of the renting and customer aspect?

Answer (score 1):

Try to read on basic [SQL stements](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/). Then try to come up with a solution on your own, and if you get stuck everyone here will be sure to help.

Comment: I tried coming up with one but it doesn't make any sense. I'll edit my post to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I envision your system working is that you would have customer data in your customer table, cd information on every cd in your inventory in the CD table, and the rent table to be the cd's that are currently checked out.  Is that how you have the tables set up?

If that is roughly how you have it setup, then I would write the query like this:

```
insert into rent(rentID, cdID, customerID,(and any other fields you have, comma separated))
values("(auto generated, or program generated rentID)","(cdID corresponding to the one being rented)","(customerID of the customer renting)","(Whatever else you're inserting)")
```

The idea is that each table will have a unique id (Primary Key) for each data item, such as an ID for each customer and an ID for each cd in inventory.  You really wouldn't need much else in the rent table except the corresponding id's and any rental pertanent data, such as check out time, date item is due to be returned, etc.  It is like a bridge connecting the other two tables.  The other tables would hold any descriptive information, such as customer name, or year a CD was made, etc., and all be linked through the unique id's.

Hope my ramblings helped.  :)